# Passing structures into functions in c

Tags: c, function, oop, struct

I want to write a simple c code to create a garden structure,input details like num_animals, type of garden and size of garden.
However, my code is giving me some garbage output.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct Garden
{
    int num_animals;
    int size;
    char type[10];
};

void Input(struct Garden gardname)
{
    printf("\nEnter number of animals\n");
    scanf("%d",&gardname.num_animals);

    printf("\nEnter size\n");
    scanf("%d",&gardname.size);

    printf("\nEnter type\n");
    scanf("%s",gardname.type);
}


void Output(struct Garden gardname)
{
    printf("Num of animals:%d\n",gardname.num_animals);
    printf("size:%d\n",gardname.size);
    printf("type:%s\n",gardname.type);
}

int main()
{
    struct Garden Lumbini;
    Input(Lumbini);
    Output(Lumbini);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The functions you have defined, by default use *call by value* method of passing arguments, which means that although you have `Lumbini` structure to which you intend to read and write elements, your functions will instead make a copy of `Lumbini`(in this case `gardname`), and write to, or print out that *copy*, not `Lumbini`. It may lead to duplicate values. I have written the same program using *call by reference* (note how a pointer to structure is the expected parameter in function, and the reference of `lumbini` is passed on call). This insures that there are no duplicates, and only the relevant structure (in this case, `lumbini`) is being manipulated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct Garden
{
    int num_animals;
    int size;
    char an_type[10];
};

void Input(struct Garden *gardname)
{
    printf("\nEnter number of animals\n");
    scanf("%d", &gardname->num_animals);

    printf("\nEnter size\n");
    scanf("%d", &gardname->size);

    printf("\nEnter type\n");
    scanf("%s", gardname->an_type);
}


void Output(struct Garden *gardname)
{
    printf("Num of animals:%d\n",gardname->num_animals);
    printf("size:%d\n",gardname->size);
    printf("type:%s\n",gardname->an_type);
}

int main()
{
    struct Garden Lumbini;
    Input(&Lumbini);
    Output(&Lumbini);

    return 0;
}
```

You are getting garbage values because `gardname` in `Output` function is a local variable to an uninitialized copy of `lumbini` structure. When you print out the values of `gardname`, they will be garbage values as they are not initialized. As the function finishes execution, `gardname` is destroyed.

Also, instead of writing

`scanf("%d",&gardname.num_animals)`

you must write

`scanf("%d", &gardname->num_animals)`

This will read into the address of pointer `gardname` plus the offset of member `num_animals` into the structure.

Comment: You need to dereference the pointer to the structure: either `(*gardname).num_animals` or (more usual) `gardname->num_animals`.

Comment: oh yes, editing my answer to include that. Thanks!

Comment: "You cannot pass a structure to a function." - That's plain wrong! While it might not be what OP wants, you very well can pass a `struct` to a function or return as a result. And C is **always** pass-by-value. There is just no pass-by reference. Pointers are types of their own right.

Comment: @olaf I see. I have edited my answer. Thanks!

Comment: As I commented already: There is no _call by reference_ in C! A pointer is not a reference, but a first class citizen.

Comment: `&gardname.num_animals` is exactly the same as `&(gardname.num_animals)`, and is nothing like `gardname->num_animals`.

Comment: Yes. My answer is wrong. It is because of local scopes and copies that there are garbage values. I am fixing my answer

Comment: You *still* have errors in the code, e.g. in your `scanf` calls.

Comment: I still see numerous errors - I suggest you compile with `gcc -Wall` and fix all the issues raised by the generated warnings, then maybe test the code once it compiles cleanly ?

Comment: @PaulR Your patience is stellar! I have compiled and tested the code in GCC 4.9.2. and it is working fine.

Comment: Well done - thanks for fixing (nearly) everything - I'm just going to make one minor edit.